# Application of derivative - finding the point on curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem :

Find the point on the curve $ay^2=x^3$ in the fourth quadrant where normal to the curve makes equal non zero intercepts with axes.

Solution :

Let the point at which normal is drawn can be given by $(x_1,y_1)$ Then it must satisfy $ay^2=x^3$

i.e. $ay_1^2=x_1^3$

= $y_1 =\pm \sqrt{\frac{x_1^3}{a}}$

Now differentiating the  given equation we get :

$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{3x^3}{2ay}$ therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(x_1,y_1) = \pm \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{x_1}{a}}$

Please guide further to clear the concepts.... thanks a lot..

Comment: Your derivative above does not appear to be correct. Why do you have $\frac{dy}{dx}$ on both sides of the equation?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives you slope of the tangent at that point [Differentiate correctly]. So find the slope of the normal at that point. Now you can write down the equation of the normal(point-slope form).
Further apply the condition on equal non zero intercepts.

Comment: @sultan Hint #2: The normal line is perpendicular to the tangent line and crosses through the same point on the function.

Answer (score -1):

Slope of tangent is $+1$ or $-1$,in $4^{\text{th}}$ quad, $x>0$, $y<0$ therefore find $dy/dx$ and put it equal to $\pm1$,  you get $x=4a/3$ and $y=-a(4/3)^{3/2}
$.